# Why React is not rendering after change in state? [functional component]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import MakeCard from './MakeCard.js';

export default function GameCards(props) {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([{}]);

  // Render component after fetching images
  useEffect(() => {
    getImages(props.cards).then(images => setImages(images));
  }, [props.cards]);

  // shuffle images and update state.
  const shuffleCards = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked");
    let newImages = images;
    for (let i = newImages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let temp, j;
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      temp = newImages[i];
      newImages[i] = images[j];
      newImages[j] = temp;
    }
    setImages(newImages);
    console.log("newImages: ", images);
  }

  if (images.length === 0) {
    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>)
  } else {
    return (<div>
      {
        images.map((image, i) => <MakeCard image={image} key={i}
          // shuffleCards={shuffleCards} 
        />)
      }
    </div>)
  }
}
```

So I am trying to make a [Memory_Card_Game](https://heldersrvio.github.io/Memory-Card-Game/) in react but when I shuffle the image array(when the user clicks on the image) which is a state variable. React does not render. I read in the documentation that react updates the virtual-DOM tree when there is a change in the state of the component. Why it isn't rendering after change in images array ?

`const [images, setImages] = useState([{}]);`

Comment: I have provided only necessary code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mutating the original images array.

You set newImages = images (which is just a reference not a copy) and then change positions in newImages.

That effectively changes the original array, and so when react compares the newImages you pass to setImages with the previous images they are the same array and so, no change is detected.

You can fix it with `let newImages = [...images];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought assigning the original array to a new variable is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your newImages array is basically the same array(same reference). Try this:

```js
const shuffleCards = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked");
    const newImages = [...images];
    for(let i = newImages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      let temp, j;
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      temp = newImages[i];
      newImages[i] = images[j];
      newImages[j] = temp;
    }
    setImages(newImages);
    console.log("newImages: ", images);
  }
```

This way we create a clone of the image array.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mutating the array and setting the state with the same reference of the array, react chooses to not re-render the component. This happens because React uses `Object.is` comparison while checking if a re-render neeeds to happens after a setState. The idea is to returns a new reference of the array and not mutate the original array. You can make it work by shallow copying the original array with spread syntax

```
const shuffleCards = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked");
    // Shallow clone the array
    let newImages = [...images];
    for(let i = newImages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      let temp, j;
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      temp = newImages[i];
      newImages[i] = images[j];
      newImages[j] = temp;
    }
    setImages(newImages);
    console.log("newImages: ", images);
  }
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

React uses [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) comparison algorithm to check for change in a state variable, in this case `images` which is an `Array`, so instead of changing in place its value, u should create a new one each time, for example:

```
const newImages = [...images]; // instead of "let newImages = images";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.